# How to add title to legend for two independent groups consisting of three subgroups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I have

[image]

The blue color indicates one group, while the red color indicated another group. As you can see, there are three `WHO==1,2,3` grades in each group.

I would like to simplify the graphics. Is it possible to add a title to the "blue string" and to the "red string"?

Expected output:

[image]

Current script

```
ggplot(b, 
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=tert_group, col=tert_group, fill=tert_group)) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1) +
  geom_point(size = 6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072"),
                     name = "",
                     labels = c("WHO-I, TERTp-wt", "WHO-I, TERT-alt", "WHO-II, TERTp-wt", "WHO-II, TERT-alt", "WHO-III, TERTp-wt", "WHO-III, TERTp-alt")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072"),.5),
                    name = "",
                    labels = c("WHO-I, TERTp-wt", "WHO-I, TERT-alt", "WHO-II, TERTp-wt", "WHO-II, TERT-alt", "WHO-III, TERTp-wt", "WHO-III, TERTp-alt")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name="",
                     values = c(21,21,22,22,24,24),
                     labels = c("WHO-I, TERTp-wt", "WHO-I, TERT-alt", "WHO-II, TERTp-wt", "WHO-II, TERT-alt", "WHO-III, TERTp-wt", "WHO-III, TERTp-alt")) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "WHO w/o TERT: Predticed risk of recurrence",
                     labels = paste0(seq(0,100,10),"%"),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,.1),
                     limits = c(0,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "WHO +TERT: Predticed risk of recurrence",
                     labels = paste0(seq(0,100,10),"%"),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,.1))
```

I tried different approaches of `name = "TERTp-wt\nTERT-alt"`, but that did not align nicely with legend text.

Data

```
b <- structure(list(wTERT = c(0.270595572606829, 0.520964343227331, 
0.272033993387013, 0.857817018869424, 0.277232269239759, 0.515411219723414, 
0.530776201033681, 0.537978816391861, 0.580089397943256, 0.272329846882174, 
0.281816598689814, 0.267523804265192, 0.586575955801609, 0.272561919226923, 
0.551067731573839, 0.575040961457171, 0.853836648872606, 0.513865922413166, 
0.275071745463873, 0.571893335762296, 0.555961759098334, 0.507670937474723, 
0.273263149407663, 0.520179490081975, 0.275298952565891, 0.521199056010643, 
0.275831552542037, 0.51268122313319, 0.26669990754491, 0.271720905718063, 
0.271087579774399, 0.571600915004122, 0.272378890421031, 0.263465014921917, 
0.518472001274984, 0.269721594792881, 0.520351505941105, 0.504346622358662, 
0.27136029515132, 0.520046182006088, 0.855693574828987, 0.276472448986918, 
0.539999936464913, 0.520401377593671, 0.507614268626494, 0.275450880251895, 
0.577062832181107, 0.512247929637022, 0.240803122800178, 0.50763956995495
), woTERT = c(0.296489465444783, 0.596498864892734, 0.297108907238502, 
0.602699790380155, 0.305069585544761, 0.587576335150488, 0.604521947458411, 
0.608453027993258, 0.299884566783421, 0.299902221096003, 0.308462348235621, 
0.294054710148313, 0.297251315754283, 0.298576329342399, 0.300810601918682, 
0.298851968053745, 0.585048328214746, 0.589265392514601, 0.300302546149141, 
0.297328944265885, 0.295424393598363, 0.579698692008963, 0.298375131334038, 
0.590188017898546, 0.30140746476472, 0.59288008651446, 0.301020050566609, 
0.583491137431191, 0.293372042721268, 0.295396218451921, 0.29655640187132, 
0.298261453439166, 0.298801473982103, 0.290540925606159, 0.588873457535114, 
0.295734684803261, 0.589402145362498, 0.575463683620961, 0.296105130790763, 
0.590311321653519, 0.588488981258673, 0.302496354158585, 0.287223763371511, 
0.59337243096153, 0.581761288026854, 0.300224806265764, 0.293940887350586, 
0.585698286452565, 0.272261078946515, 0.58056413840941), tert_group = c("WHO-II0", 
"WHO-III0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-III1", "WHO-II0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-III0", 
"WHO-III0", "WHO-II1", "WHO-II0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-II1", 
"WHO-II0", "WHO-II1", "WHO-II1", "WHO-III1", "WHO-III0", "WHO-II0", 
"WHO-II1", "WHO-II1", "WHO-III0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-II0", 
"WHO-II0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-II0", 
"WHO-II1", "WHO-II0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-III0", 
"WHO-II0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-III1", "WHO-II0", "WHO-I1", 
"WHO-III0", "WHO-III0", "WHO-II0", "WHO-II1", "WHO-III0", "WHO-I0", 
"WHO-III0")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(b, 
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=tert_group, col=tert_group, fill=tert_group)) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1) +
  geom_point(size = 6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072"),
                     name = "TERTp-wt\n\nTERT-alt",
                     labels = c("WHO-I, TERTp-wt", "WHO-I, TERT-alt", "WHO-II, TERTp-wt", "WHO-II, TERT-alt", "WHO-III, TERTp-wt", "WHO-III, TERTp-alt")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072","#2C77BF","#E38072"),.5),
                    name = "TERTp-wt\n\nTERT-alt",
                    labels = c("WHO-I, TERTp-wt", "WHO-I, TERT-alt", "WHO-II, TERTp-wt", "WHO-II, TERT-alt", "WHO-III, TERTp-wt", "WHO-III, TERTp-alt")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name="TERTp-wt\n\nTERT-alt",
                     values = c(21,21,22,22,24,24),
                     labels = c("WHO-I, TERTp-wt", "WHO-I, TERT-alt", "WHO-II, TERTp-wt", "WHO-II, TERT-alt", "WHO-III, TERTp-wt", "WHO-III, TERTp-alt")) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "WHO w/o TERT: Predticed risk of recurrence",
                     labels = paste0(seq(0,100,10),"%"),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,.1),
                     limits = c(0,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "WHO +TERT: Predticed risk of recurrence",
                     labels = paste0(seq(0,100,10),"%"),
                     breaks = seq(0,1,.1))+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(face='bold',size=9))
```

Output:

[image]